# What does "the function is frequency localized" mean

Tags: fourier-analysis, terminology

I am studying Littlewood-Paley theory, one sentence says "the function is frequency localized", what does that mean?

Comment: Possibly that when looking at the frequency spectrum, most of the energy lies in a narrow band.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us *what* function that sentence is about?

Comment: It means that the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ of the function $f$ vanishes outside an interval $[-R,R]$ for some $R$. The result is that $f(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}e^{ist}\hat{f}(s)ds$, which extends everywhere in the complex plane to a Holomorphic function of bounded exponential order. (And that characterizes such functions $f$.)